Identify movie with fat guy's tie getting stuck in plane door
I remember seeing a movie about 5 years ago, though it had an older 80s feel to it, and I remember only a few details from it.

Fat guy's tie gets stuck in trunk of a car, and car drives off with him hanging on for dear life
Same fat guy's tie gets stuck in door of small Jet, and jet starts taking off (this is toward the very end of the movie)
American military veteran lives in a schoolbus surrounded by land mines
Fat guy's brother/cousin/(something like that) is running for a public office
Fat guy and brother borrow a friend's police car with a broken tape player, and a leaky NO2 booster (which causes them to get high and drive at 7mph on the interstate - they get pulled over)

Can anyone identify this movie for me?

Ten bucks says this is Chris Farley, either Tommy Boy or Black sheep.

How far back did you see it though.

About 5 years ago maybe.

But I think it was an 80s movie, because 'It's Pat' came on right after.

Did it look like a 2010 movie, or did it look older?

Black Sheep (1996), by the late Chris Farley as Mike Donnelly, the incompetent brother of Al Donnelly, who's running for Governor of Washington.
Tie stuck in car trunk:



Gary Busey as the Schoolbus Veteren:



Farley's character attempting to get people to vote for his brother:



Farley pulled over for driving 7 MPH:



Coat stuck in plane door:



